# Diacritic placement with Adobe Garamond

Tags: font-identification

My question is due to the sample of [Al-Jāhiẓ: In praise of Books](http://www.euppublishing.com/userimages/ContentEditor/1390478796299/Montgomery%20-%20Al-Jahiz%20-%20In%20Praise%20of%20Books%20-%20Sample%20Chapter.pdf). The fourth page states that the book was typeset in Adobe Garamond.

I'm concerned with the diacritics for letters such as 'ẓ'. I could not find this in Adobe Garamond Pro using Typekit. Furthermore, the italic version seems different; it looks slanted instead of being italicized.

So the question: is there a version of Adobe Garamond which has the needed diacritics such as: ṣ, ṭ, ẓ, ḥ, ā, ū, ī, ḍ?

If not, how was it achieved in the sample?

Comment: The Garamond italics in that PDF are definitely true italics, not merely faux-italic slanted text.

Answer (score 1):

Try [EB Garamond](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/EB+Garamond). Access these special characters in the **Glyphs Panel** in Photoshop (`Window > Glyphs`) or Illustrator (`Window > Type > Glyphs`):

[image]

Comment: The PDF OP linked to apparently uses "Stempel Garamond" although the Linotype version of that looks like it doesn't have the glyphs needed

Comment: I saw that too. Not sure why Adobe Garamond Pro or Garamond Premier Pro wouldn't include these glyphs.

Comment: I want to know how to get those glyphs in Adobe Garamond just like in the PDF. I know these glyphs exists in another Adobe font, "Adobe Text Pro" but I'd really like to use Adobe Garamond.

Comment: Unless there's a different font package for [Adobe Garamond Pro](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/type/pdfs/AdobeGaramondPro.pdf), it seems that the subscript dot accent is not included (see link). Keep in mind, Adobe Garamond Pro is a revised, updated version of Adobe Garamond, so it's possible some features (i.e., glyphs) were omitted to include others more commonly used.

Comment: If you copy the text out of the PDF, the subscript-dot characters are not what they seem: al-JāªiÕ, not al-Jāḥiẓ. Looks like they used a special lookalike font for the odd characters.